# How can I create a View in Oracle with a String column whose content is aggregated from numeric values of related entities?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, listagg

In a Java application based on an Oracle SQL database, I have the following problem to solve:

An entity `DataDelivery` can consist of any number of `Packet`. 
`Packet` has a `ReportDate` and the the foreign key `datadeliveryid`.

`ReportDate` is of Datatype NUMBER(4,0) and contains the year (YYYY) for example 2020, or 2018. The column `ReportDate` is in in table PACKET.

In my view, I want to display the `DataDelivery` as table rows including a column that displays the combined report date (YYYY) of all pertaining packets. 
The combined ReportDate of the Packets shall be a comma separated list.

**Important:** When a year such as '2018' occurs multiple times, it shall not be repeated.

So, a DataDelivery with 3 Packets as follows:

```
DataDelivery
    PACKET1, ReportDate:2020
    PACKET2, ReportDate:2020
    PACKET3, ReportDate:2018
    PACKET4, ReportDate: `null`

shall be displayed as:    2018, 2020
```

That means, `null` must be ignored, 2020 must not be repeated.
And the values must be **sorted** in ascending order.

If all packets have a null value as ReportDate, the value in the view must be empty.

---

For simplicity's sake, I ommitted some of the complexity of my problem including several joins, etc. Also, the dates can only be `2018`, `2020`, or `null`, although it would be nicer to remove this constraint. Perhaps someone can suggest a solution based on what I tried here:

```
            CASE
                WHEN COUNT(CASE eqpaket.berichtszeitraum WHEN 2020 THEN 2020 END) = COUNT(*) THEN '2020'
                WHEN COUNT(CASE eqpaket.berichtszeitraum WHEN 2018 THEN 2018 END) = COUNT(*) THEN '2018'
                WHEN COUNT(distinct eqpaket.berichtszeitraum) > 1 THEN
                    listagg(eqpaket.berichtszeitraum, ',') within group(order by datenlieferungid)
                ELSE ''
            END AS berichtszeitraum,
```

This works great, when all ReportDates are the same. When they differ, I get duplicates. In the example above I would get: `2018, 2020, 2020`. Those duplicates need to be removed, and this must happen within the CASE -- END, if I stick to this approach.

Comment: See [Oracle String Aggregation techniques](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/tag/listagg/)

Comment: @LalitKumarB - there is nothing in the link you provided regarding **distinct** values in the aggregation.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, I need to update the link with new distinct feature in 19c. For now, distinct could be done in a subquery first. The purpose of the link was to provide various methods which are supported prior to 11gR2 like MODEL etc. Or even older sys_connect_by_path approach in 9i etc.

Answer (score 0):

for Oracle 11g and higher  you could use listagg

```
select listagg(distinct ReportDate, ',') within group (order by ReportDate)
from DataDelivery
```

Comment: Please take a look at my edited question. I am using `listagg` but there is still a problem.

Comment: `listagg` is available since Oracle 11.2; however, the `distinct` option was only added in Oracle 19.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps (as your database version doesn't support `listagg` with `distinct`):

```
SQL> with datedelivery (datedeliveryid, packet, reportdate) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 1, 'packet1', 2020 from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'packet2', 2020 from dual union all
  5     select 1, 'packet3', 2018 from dual union all
  6     select 1, 'packet4', null from dual union all
  7     --
  8     select 2, 'packet5', 2017 from dual union all
  9     select 2, 'packet6', 2017 from dual union all
 10     select 2, 'packet7', null from dual
 11    )
 12  -- query you need
 13  select datedeliveryid,
 14         listagg(reportdate, ', ') within group (order by reportdate) years
 15  from (-- first find DISTINCT values, then aggregate them
 16        select distinct datedeliveryid, reportdate
 17        from datedelivery
 18       )
 19  group by datedeliveryid;

DATEDELIVERYID YEARS
-------------- --------------------
             1 2018, 2020
             2 2017

SQL>
```